# Enable smilies/emoticons in UCWA Chat application

Tags: instant-messaging, emoticons, ucwa

I have built a web application which provides simple text chatting. I have used the UCWA API provided by Microsoft to implement this Instant Messaging chat application.

My next step is to enable usage of smilies/emoticons in the chat application. I have gone though the ucwa documentation [https://ucwa.lync.com/documentation](https://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/what-is-lync-ucwa-api)

But i have not found a way to enable usage of smilies/emoticons.

My query is: Does UCWA API support usage of smilies/emoticons? If yes, how do we enable in our chat application. If No, how can we add smilies/emoticons into a web application?

Any sort of links or any clues would be really helpful. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple Answer

*Most* Smilies/Emoticons are a translation of a string of characters into a visible image.

Examples:

- :) ==> [image: Smiley Face]
- (bah) ==> [image: Sheep]

UCWA has no knowledge of the image assets nor would you want it tossing around image data when in most cases a textual representation would result in a smaller response message.  **There is no native support**.

Smilies/Emoticons that appear in Lync Client are a result of the application translating the string into an image resource.  If you were to send a **:)**, Lync Client *should* translate it to a [image: Smiley Face].

### What can I do?

- Translate local display of **supported** Smilies/Emoticons to their image counter parts. (*Probably the easiest*)
- Support sending of Html messages and send the Smilie/Emoticon and hope the receiving participant can access the image resource defined in an  tag. (*Probably the worst idea*)
- Make use of [Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) since UCWA is able to send/receive UTF encoded messages.  Consider extensive testing to make sure that deployed environments can correctly display the results!